# Nestjs/TypeORM Cannot connect to Docker MariaDB

Tags: javascript, docker, mariadb, nestjs, typeorm

Whenever I run my docker image containing nodejs 11.10 & mariadb, I get the following error:

> [Nest] 16   - 3/12/2019, 11:24:02 AM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to
>   connect to the database. Retrying (9)... +3587msError: EPERM:
>   operation not permitted, scandir
>   '/proc/1/map_files/559e63542000-559e656d1000'
>       at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:807:3)    at GlobSync._readdir (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)
>       at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:267:20)
>       at GlobSync._readdir (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:276:17)
>       at GlobSync._processReaddir (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:137:22)
>       at GlobSync._process (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)
>       at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:380:10)
>       at GlobSync._process (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
>       at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:383:10)
>       at GlobSync._process (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)

The same issue happens when I use `mysql:latest` & `mysql:5.6`. This is my connection:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mariadb',
  host: '172.17.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'nest',
  password: 'secret',
  database: 'nest',
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
}),
```

Has anyone else ever had this issue, and so, know how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because of `entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],`. Because `__dirname` does somehow not resolve to your projects directory but `''` instead, it will try to scan your whole drive for entities and obviously does not have the permissions to do so.

### Workaround

Instead of scanning for entities, list them explicitly:

```
entities: [UserEntity, ProductEntity],
```

---

If you are using webpack for hmr, you can also try the following config to resolve `__dirname` correctly:

webpack.config.js:

```
node: {
  __dirname: false,
},
```

Comment: I created an ormconfig.json file without the dirname part and it fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out:

```
entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}']
```

Note the starting path `'/../'` mean start scanning from absolute path.